# Export a KEA segmented file as shp or raster, using segment ID numbers

Tags: export

I have a KEA dataset of which the RAT has numerous columns. There are 11919 segments.  I want to export this dataset either as shp or raster keeping the segment ID numbers, i.e. I want a shapefile or raster with only the segment numbers connected to the segments.

How do I do this?

I tried rastergis.exportGDALCols.Image in Python using RSGisLib but since the segment ID number column doesn't have a column name, that didn't work.
I was able to export the RAT as a csv in Python with an additional column that contains segment numbers, but I need a shp or raster dataset to give me the spatial information of the segments.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS SE! Please take the [tour]. Regarding your question, what software do you use? It's also a plus if you provide information about what you already have tried to reach your goal. So, edit your question with further helpful context to get an answer to your question.

Comment: What software is this?

Comment: Thanks for your reactions, I have edited the question, I hope it's clearer now. I've also added a solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution - gdal_polygonize.py gave me exactly what I needed, a shp with the segment IDnumbers as attribute.